# Chrome 49 timing and loading errors using require.js modules

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, requirejs, amd

My web app (which has lots of JS) has been working fine until this Chrome 49 update. (I know it's the update because it was working, then I updated my browser, and now its not).

There seems to be a timing issue on when the require.js `define()` functions are called. Although the require.js files are loaded first, my non-amd JS loaded after are firing first and causing issues like:

`Uncaught Error: Module name [name] has not been loaded...`

Is anyone else having this problem?

Comment: Off topic? No "clear problem statement"? Please. The title states very clearly what the problem is: "Chrome 49 timing and loading errors using require.js modules". Require js modules are loading differently after Chrome 49 was released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this is the case, but my app entry point which begins to use all my loaded JS was wrapped with:

```
$(function() {

  //...Start app

})
```

And I changed it to:

```
require([], function(){

  //...Start app

})
```

I first tried `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){` but that didn't work any better. But wrapping with `require()` did. Hopefully this helps someone.